# How do I override the default DPI in DOMPDF's config file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf laravel wrapper around DOMPDF.

I am generating letters to be printed and posted with different letterheads and I have the letterhead as a background image with the text over the top.

I have got to the point where everything is working well, however, the default DPI in DOMPDF is 96 so the background image of the letterhead is quite low resolution when printed out.

I know there is a `def("DOMPDF_DPI", 96);` option in the dompdf_config.inc file within the vendor directory. How do I override this setting without editing the file within the package itself?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

Running php artisan vendor:publish gave me a config file in my directory where I could edit this option.

```
/**
     * Image DPI setting
     *
     * This setting determines the default DPI setting for images and fonts.  The
     * DPI may be overridden for inline images by explictly setting the
     * image's width & height style attributes (i.e. if the image's native
     * width is 600 pixels and you specify the image's width as 72 points,
     * the image will have a DPI of 600 in the rendered PDF.  The DPI of
     * background images can not be overridden and is controlled entirely
     * via this parameter.
     *
     * For the purposes of DOMPDF, pixels per inch (PPI) = dots per inch (DPI).
     * If a size in html is given as px (or without unit as image size),
     * this tells the corresponding size in pt.
     * This adjusts the relative sizes to be similar to the rendering of the
     * html page in a reference browser.
     *
     * In pdf, always 1 pt = 1/72 inch
     *
     * Rendering resolution of various browsers in px per inch:
     * Windows Firefox and Internet Explorer:
     *   SystemControl->Display properties->FontResolution: Default:96, largefonts:120, custom:?
     * Linux Firefox:
     *   about:config *resolution: Default:96
     *   (xorg screen dimension in mm and Desktop font dpi settings are ignored)
     *
     * Take care about extra font/image zoom factor of browser.
     *
     * In images, <img> size in pixel attribute, img css style, are overriding
     * the real image dimension in px for rendering.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    "DOMPDF_DPI" => 192,
```

Answer (score 0):

That file lives in your vendor folder, you should never touch it as /vendor should be in your .gitignore file anyways.

You should really use the original Dompdf library https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
and do something like

```
$options = (new Options)->setDpi($yourDpi);
$dom = new DompdfWrapper($options);
$dom->loadHtml($htmlString);
$dom->render();
```

Comment: What Elthomson wrote is right. Using the command vendor:publish, a file is copied in the config folder and in this folder you can modify the file. Following his method, you don't modify anything in the vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

I use DOMPDF v1.0.2 with Code Igniter. Very simple solution:

```
require_once("application/libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option("dpi", 300);
```